# IF / Case statment in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, case-statement

I have a column where I have 0 or 1. I like to do the following set up:

If 0 than put / use the Region_table (here I have regions like EMEA, AP,LA with finished goods only) and when it 1 then put / use the Plant_table (here I have plants with non-finished goods) data's.

[image]

I tried to write it in 2 different statements but it is not good:

```
,Case 

when [FG_NFG_Selektion]  = '0'  Then 'AC_region' 

End as 'AC_region' 

,Case

when [FG_NFG_Selektion]  = '1'  Then 'AC_plant'

End as 'AC_plant'
```

Comment: Please give a sample of tables and data with your expected result, this is quite difficult to understand without more detailed information

Comment: Use the table based on a value of the column? Where is that column?

Comment: Make it possible to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're looking for, but if you want to get data from different tables based on the value in the `[FG_NFG_Selektion]` field, you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN [FG_NFG_Selektion] = '0' THEN r.some_col -- If 0, use value from "region" table
    WHEN [FG_NFG_Selektion] = '1' THEN p.some_col -- If 1, use value from "plant" table
  END AS new_field
FROM MyTable t
LEFT JOIN AC_region r ON t.pk_col = r.pk_col -- get data from "AC_region" table
LEFT JOIN AC_plant p ON t.pk_col = p.pk_col -- get data from "AC_plant" table
;
```

If `[FG_NFG_Selektion]` is a numeric field, then you should remove the single quotes: `[FG_NFG_Selektion] = 0`.

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for!
I made a misstake after the THEN that i put the table in ' '.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend putting the conditions in the `ON` clauses:

```
SELECT COALESCE(r.some_col, p.some_col) as som_col
FROM t LEFT JOIN
     AC_region r
     ON t.pk_col = r.pk_col AND
        t.FG_NFG_Selektion = '0' LEFT JOIN
     AC_plant p
     ON t.pk_col = p.pk_col AND
        t.FG_NFG_Selektion = '1';
```

Why do I recommend this?  First, this works correctly if there are multiple matches in either table.  That is probably not an issue *in this case*, but it could be in others.  You don't want to figure out where extra rows come from.

Second, putting the conditions in the `ON` clause allows the optimizer/execution engine to take advantage of them.  For instance, it is more likely to use `FG_NFG_Selektion` in an index.